# How to deploy Laravel 5.1 application to CentOS 6.4 VPS (or any!) server (PHP 5.5.32)

Tags: php, centos, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 application that I'm trying to deploy on my CentOS 6.4 VPS server. The problem is that I am getting Error 500 when trying to load the page. When I check the error log it shows me this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/home/pams/pams_todo_list/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/pams/pams_todo_list/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87

I have changed the permissions in `pams_todo_list/storage` and `pams_todo_list/vendors` to 777 instead of 755 as a test, but no love.

Comment: did you try setting permission to all folder? sudo chmod 755 -R /home/pams/pams_todo_list ?

Comment: I just did, no love.

Comment: You should change it recursively (use -R) as @CanCelik said, however not to 755 but to 777, i.e.: chmod -R 777 /home/pams/pams_todo_list/storage/logs (however its always best to change the owner/group than enable perms to all)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, thanks to `FFForever` and `lagbox` on the Laravel IRC channel.

My owner permissions were wrong. I had inadvertently uploaded the project using the root account. The fix was two fold. First, I setup `suPHP` as my php handler (I do have root access to this server) through the EasyApache3 UI in WHM. Then I set the owner:

> chown -R pams:pams pams_todo_list

Now it works. I cannot say if it would have worked without setting up `suPHP`, however it was strongly recommended to set that up, so I did.